# How to map a collection of entities, inside an entity, using Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, maven

I'm developing a distributed software system and I'm trying to use the Hibernate framework for the first time. One of my classes (which is a mapped Entity) has an ArrayList<> containing objects of another class (which is also an Entity).

Ex:

I have an Event class, which is a @MappedSuperclass.

I have a CorporateEvent class, which is an entity, that inherits from Event.

I have a Task class, which is also an Entity.

My CorporateEvent class has an attribute called "tasks", which is an ArrayList.

How do I map this correctly to the database so that there's a table called Event and a table called Task, which has a key connecting them to eachother?

I'm using the newest Hibernate version and the database is on a PostgreSQL server. The dialect in Hibernate is set to PostgreSQL.

We've tried using @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable, but we're getting some weird NullPointerExceptions. It might have something to do with the inheritance aspect of the code.

Here is the 3 classes in question:

Event Class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

public abstract class Event {

   @Column(name="title")
   private String title;

   @Column(name="location")
   private String location;

   @Column(name="date")
   private String date;
```

CorporateEvent Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="corporate_event")

public class CorporateEvent extends Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "corporate_event_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    private ArrayList<Task> tasks;

    @Column(name="expenses")
    private String expenses;
```

Task Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="task")

public class Task {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "task_task_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
  @Column(name="task_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private int id;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String taskName;

  @Column(name="description")
  private String description;
```

I expect the output to be that a CorporateEvent object is saved to the database and the Task objects in its ArrayList are each saved in the Task table with a CorporateEvent ID that connects them to the right event.

What I instead get is a NullPointerException on the line where I try to save the CorporateEvent object using Hibernate. This is the error message:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Eventer 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Eventer ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 11 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ Eventer ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ Eventer ---
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:30 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.8.Final}
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:30 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://tek-mmmi-db0a.tek.c.sdu.dk:5432/si3_2019_group_5_db]
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=si3_2019_group_5, password=****}
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:31 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:35 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000503: A class should not be annotated with both @Inheritance and @MappedSuperclass. @Inheritance will be ignored for: com.mycompany.domain.event.Event.
Nov 08, 2019 5:31:35 PM org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl addIdentifierGenerator
WARN: HHH000069: Duplicate generator name id_generator
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.repositories.EventRepository.saveCorporateEvent(EventRepository.java:51)
    at com.mycompany.eventer.Eventer.main(Eventer.java:42)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 7.007s
Finished at: Fri Nov 08 17:31:35 CET 2019
Final Memory: 9M/100M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project Eventer: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

The line it complains about is "session.close();" in this method:

```
public int saveCorporateEvent(CorporateEvent corporateEvent) {

        try {
            session = ConnectRepository.factory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(corporateEvent);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return corporateEvent.getId();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

And if I remove the session.close(); I get the following annotation error, which I don't understand, since an ArrayList should be supported?:

(The beginning is the same, so I'm only pasting the difference in)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mycompany.repositories.EventRepository.saveCorporateEvent(EventRepository.java:42)
    at com.mycompany.eventer.Eventer.main(Eventer.java:42)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.util.ArrayList collection type not supported for property: com.mycompany.domain.event.CorporateEvent.tasks
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1939)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:975)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.mycompany.repositories.ConnectRepository.<clinit>(ConnectRepository.java:27)
    ... 2 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 11.877s
Finished at: Fri Nov 08 17:44:27 CET 2019
Final Memory: 19M/208M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project Eventer: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

**UPDATE:**
Now it's somewhat working. But a new problem has appeared. As you can see below, hibernate only inserts into the CorporateEvent table, not the task table.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Eventer 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Eventer ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 11 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ Eventer ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ Eventer ---
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:21 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.8.Final}
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:21 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://tek-mmmi-db0a.tek.c.sdu.dk:5432/si3_2019_group_5_db]
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=si3_2019_group_5, password=****}
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:22 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:26 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000503: A class should not be annotated with both @Inheritance and @MappedSuperclass. @Inheritance will be ignored for: com.mycompany.domain.event.Event.
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:26 PM org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl addIdentifierGenerator
WARN: HHH000069: Duplicate generator name id_generator
Nov 10, 2019 12:15:26 PM org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl addIdentifierGenerator
WARN: HHH000069: Duplicate generator name id_generator
Hibernate: select nextval ('corporate_event_id_seq')
Hibernate: insert into corporate_event (date, description, location, max_participants, title, expenses, corporate_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 9.780s
Finished at: Sun Nov 10 12:15:28 CET 2019
Final Memory: 9M/100M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These are the changes I made using your help:

CorporateEvent class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="corporateEvent")
    private List<Task> tasks;
```

Task class:

```
@ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="corporate_id")
  private CorporateEvent corporateEvent;
```

The code runs successfully, but it will not map the data to the Task table in my database. This is the test (main) code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Task> arrTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        arrTasks.add(new Task("task1", "taskDes1"));
        arrTasks.add(new Task("task2", "taskDes2"));
        arrTasks.add(new Task("task3", "taskDes3"));
        User user = new User("alex", "tholle", "sdu", "software engineering", "at@gmail.com", 70111213, "alexuser", "alexpass", new Date(), true, "student", "e2R213");
        Meetup meetup = new Meetup(user.getUserName(), "meetup at the pub", "old irish", new Date().toString(), "det bliver fed", 10);
        Task task = new Task("Cleaning", "Do some cleaing please");
        CorporateEvent corporateEvent = new CorporateEvent(null, arrTasks, "Tinderbox", "forest", new Date().toString(), "edm music festival", 5000);

        for (Task t : arrTasks) {
            t.setCorporateEvent(corporateEvent);
        }

        EventRepository eventRepo = new EventRepository();
        eventRepo.saveCorporateEvent(corporateEvent);
```

The database has the following tables regarding this issue:

```
create table task
(
    task_id      serial not null
        constraint task_pk
            primary key,
    name         varchar,
    description  varchar(1000),
    corporate_id integer
        constraint corporate_id
            references corporate_event
            on update cascade on delete cascade
);

alter table task
    owner to si3_2019_group_5;

create unique index task_task_id_uindex
    on task (task_id);
```

```
create table corporate_event
(
    title            varchar,
    date             varchar(1000),
    location         varchar,
    description      varchar,
    max_participants integer,
    expenses         varchar(2000),
    corporate_id     serial not null
        constraint corporate_event_pk
            primary key,
    tasks            varchar(4000)
);

alter table corporate_event
    owner to si3_2019_group_5;

create unique index corporate_event_id_uindex
    on corporate_event (corporate_id);
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a regular `@OneToMany` with a `Set<Task>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is likely due to your usage of the @ElementCollection annotation without a class that is annotated with @Embeddable. I would use a [OneToMany](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) annotation implementation instead.

Your CorporateEvent class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="corporate_event")
private List<Task> tasks;
```

Your Task class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="corporate_event_id")
private CorporateEvent corporateEvent;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, it helped move the project to the next step, which in turn created a new problem. Could you please look at the update and see if you have a suggestion for a fix. The new problem is that hibernate does not create entries in the task table, only the corporateEvent table.